# Cannot configure Eclipse Server runtime for JBoss Web 2.1.9.GA

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss-web

I am having trouble using my local JBoss Web 2.1.9.GA instance within my local Eclipse installation as a Server Runtime Environment.

Our client uses JBoss Web 2.1.9.GA instead of a standard Tomcat 6 installation, and so I am required to test and debug with a local JBoss Web 2.1.9.GA instance. Now, I am aware that JBoss Web is simply a rebranded and only slightly modified version of Tomcat 6, but when I try to use the "Apache > Apache Tomcat v6.0" server runtime as my choice, and then select the server base folder on my machine, I receive the following error at the top of the dialog:

The Apache Tomcat installation at this directory is version 2.1.9.GA.  A Tomcat 6.0 installation is expected.

I am unsure how to get this working as it is intended to work at this point; there doesn't seem to be any options that will accept a JBoss Web 2.1.9.GA server folder. There also seems to be practically zero information online concerning the use of JBoss Web within Eclipse.

For context, I am using the SpringSource Tool Suite v2.9.2.RELEASE pre-packaged Eclipse install on a MacBook Pro running OS 10.7.4. It *shouldn't* matter however, java is java, and Eclipse is Eclipse, yes?

Has anyone had experience and luck with this?

Tom Harris

(I posted this question on Feb 22, but there was still no answer on March 5, so I am appending this note and rewording the question a bit.)

Comment: I don't know if my tutorial about a completely different topic may be helpful for you (see the first part, points 4-5):  http://yatb.giacomodrago.com/en/post/7/tutorial-restful-web-service-ejb-hibernate-jpa-jboss.html It also deals with how to link JBoss AS 7.1 with Eclipse Indigo. I think you can consider switching to JBoss AS, it incorporates the functionalities of JBoss Web (which is obsolete).
If this is not helpful, just ignore this comment.

Comment: I don't have the authority to switch my client to AS, and they really only need Tomcat, since this is just servlets and JSPs involved here. But thanks for the link; I'm sure I will find a reason to use AS 7 at some point.